# Count number of file in each subdirectory python

Tags: python, python-os

I am trying to get the count of all files listed in all directories as well as the count of files inside individual directories. Below is my code to get the total count of files in all directories but I am unable to get how to get the count within individual directory. Can some one please help?

```
N = 0 #Total count of number of files in all directories
N_c = 0 #Number of documents in each class

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(filePath):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames]:
        files = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename)]
        for f in files:
            N+=1
```

Comment: Instead of using one variable for the count, use a dictionary where keys are directory names.

Comment: How do you want to record the count in each directory? Just print?

Comment: I am using the variable N_c to record the Number of documents in each directory

Comment: I don't understand what that means. N_c is one variable... how do you want it to hold counts of many directories? How is it different than the count for all directories?

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the solution with your help. Below is the code    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(filePath):
        N += len(filenames)
        print("Files in", dirpath, len(filenames))
        for dir in [d for d in dirpath]:
            for n in dir:
                N_c = len(filenames)
        print N_c
    print N

Answer (score 7):

In **user7737327** answer:
you do not need to iterate over the `dirpath` and `for d in dirpath`

`filenames` contain a list of all files in current directory.
We can just take the length of filenames to get the number of files in current directory.

```
N = 0  # total files
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(file_path):
    N_c = len(filenames)
    N += N_c
    print "Files in ", dirpath, N_c
print "Total Files ",N
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working too hard. You have a list of filenames, just take its length. I don't know what you mean by "the count of files inside individual directories" so I am just printing them.

```
N = 0 #Total count of number of files in all directories
# what is this supposed to be?
# N_c = 0 #Number of documents in each class

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(filePath):
    N += len(filenames)
    print("Files in", dirpath, len(filenames)

print("Total files", N)
```

Comment: I need the total count of files in all subdirectories which i am storing in variable N and the files inside each individual directory for which I have taken the N_c variable. I need to scan every directory inside the main directory and then take the file counts and store in N_c

Comment: How do you store all of the counts in one variable? How is it different than the total?

Comment: Suppose you had 3 subdirectories with 1, 2, and 3 files. The total would be 6. What would N_c be?

Comment: for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(filePath):
        N += len(filenames)
        print("Files in", dirpath, len(filenames))
        for dir in [d for d in dirpath]:
            for n in dir:
                N_c = len(filenames)
        print N_c
    print N

Comment: Hi I figured it out. This is the code. Thank you so much for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), a recursive glob and `sum`:

```
from pathlib import Path 

fc=sum(1 for fn in Path(ur_path).glob('**/*') if fn.is_file())
```

If you want a count by directory rather than a total:

```
dirs={}
for fn in Path(ur_path).glob('**/*'):
    if fn.is_file():
        key=str(fn.parent)
        dirs[key]=dirs.get(key, 0)+1
```

Which can easily be used for a total as well:

```
fc=sum(dirs.values())
```

Or,

```
print(f'{sum(dirs.values())} files in {sum(1 for _ in dirs.keys())} directories')
```